# recover a phone number I didn't save

Tags: data-recovery

At the bar last night I got a number I opened a new contact under my Google contacts on my Droid Incredible and typed in the information.  But in my sub lucid state I never saved it, I would love to call this girl but the number is lost to me, any thoughts on how I might get the digits back?

Comment: You typed the number in, right? Always helps to get someone to call you right there to get the number, or call them back to make sure you got it right. Added bonus that it goes into calls list...

Comment: If you didn't call the number afraid you lost it forever...

Comment: In your sub-lucid state, maybe it wasn't a girl.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry but there is no way to recover the phone number unless that persons number called/text you or you made a call/text to that person. If you did that you could go into your call history and see the made/missed call and then add it to your contacts.

A habit to get into is dial the number first and then hang up. That way its in your call history. Then from your call history add the number to your contacts and add additional info such as name, address and email. If you do this and forget to click save at least you still have the telephone number on your phone.

Answer (score 0):

It will probably not help you for now but maybe next time.

If you are in an edit contact screen and you press on the home button before you saved the contact, there are chances that this screen would still be active but you need to get back into the app using the "recent apps" list. In my case (Galaxy S3), if I long-press the home button it shows me the list of recently used applications and if I select one from the list it goes back to it in the state it was before I pressed home.

If I go back to the same application by re-selecting it from the main screen icon then it goes back to the default view of the application.

And this rule is true for a lot of applications, that is why I always use the "recent apps" list when multitasking to prevent the app to start again from the default view.

Comment: Try it now anyway because I don't think there is a limit on the time Android keeps the last state of an application. It will loose it only if the OS needs the memory at some point or if you reboot obviously.